# nuget local package source is unable to find package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to build some packages for use within my company.  I've set up a local folder on my hard drive and added it as a package source before the official nuget source.  when I execute `nuget list janney`, my packages are found however executing `install-package janney.myfirstpackage` throws an error `Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Janney.MyFirstPackage'.`

What am I doing wrong?  Is this an indication that I've messed up my packages?

Answer (score 7):

In my package manager console my package source was set to nuget rather than all

Comment: And for others in my boat: If the package source folder contains only prerelease packages, don't forget the `-IncludePrerelease` ;)

Comment: How do you fix this from the CLI?